SSD partitioning on Linux (data loss)
I wanted to create new partition on SSD (i need it to create disk image using clonezilla).

I started from creating while I'm on ssd boot (means the system is running on ssd.
Then i got message: ssd in use, may be data loss.
I booted from USB, using terminal and fdisk created new 100gb partition
After this i found out that maybe my system was installed on full ssd drive without any partition (because after partition creation i see only one, newly created)
Since this i tried to boot from ssd, not from USB, and got message that there is no boot option
I booted from usb again, using testdisk find all lost data, but the problem is it cannot be restored

So my question is: how is it possible no partition was created while linux installation, what should i do no, is it possible to restore system at all or no?
Thanks for you answers and suggestions!

Data recovery software like Testdisk/Photorec can recover individual files, never the system as it was. Use it to recover personal files and those files only, then reinstall the OS with the partitioning layout you want. Next time pay attention to the warning and error messages. You can create any partition in any drive provided there's unallocated  space. When there isn't you'll inevitably overwrite the partition table. You can't make a new partition out of free space of another unless you first resize (shrink) it, obviously.

The bootloader has to go somewhere so unless you had another bootable device, its unlikely to not have a partition table. Technically its possible to not use one (and often leads to data loss). Did you format the partition you created? That's usually where all data is discarded then...
